# Does ag-grid 20.0 support server-side pagination?

Tags: pagination, version, ag-grid-angular

Is server side pagination possible in ag-grid 20.0 version?

I would like to have ag-grid which makes an API call every time the page number is changed. Please let me know if this is possible in 20.0 version. Thanks!